# any solution for django template multiple inheriting?

Tags: python, django, templates

ie:
   template A require data B,template C require data D,template E require data F,
   template C and E inherited from template A.
so while rendering template C or E,how to pass the data B to template A?
my solution is passing data B and (data D or data F) while rendering template C or E.Is there any better solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859769/django-multiple-template-inheritance-is-this-the-right-style

Comment: thanks!i now using the inclusion_tag,thats great.